# what should i do to fix this ? /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l

Tags: 14.10

hello please help me I have tried everything

```
sudo apt-get -f install 
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

everything that I could find but i still get these error when I do make command

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLU
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXmu
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXext
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXi

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 7):

You need several development packages to build your program.

Open a terminal and install the following packages (as they are not installed by default):

```
sudo apt-get install libxmu-dev libxmu-headers freeglut3-dev libxext-dev libxi-dev
```

Then restart your `make` process.

Comment: In my case (pip installing lxml) i needed : `zlib1g-dev`